# Which PIP Returns Global Instead of VirtualEnv

Tags: python, django, git, macos, virtualenv

I am setting up a Django app to run on Apache using WSGI. I created a virtualenv inside the project's directory on my Mac, installed Django in there and made sure it worked.

I get the following results on the Mac after I run `source ./virt_name/bin/activate`:

`which python` -> `/Users/user/www/sites/Playground/Django-tut/app_name/app-env/bin/python`

`which python3` -> `/Users/user/www/sites/Playground/Django-tut/app_name/app-env/bin/python3`

`which pip` -> `/Users/user/www/sites/Playground/Django-tut/app_name/app-env/bin/pip`

I then take the same app directory and transfer it (using Git) to an EC2 instance. After I activate the virtual environment (seemingly successfully), I get the following:

`which python` -> `/usr/bin/python`

`which python3` -> `/usr/bin/python3`

`which pip` -> `/usr/bin/pip`

Is this an expected behavior? How can I fix this? It is my understanding that when one activates a virtualenv, the binaries should be "picked up" from there instead of the system directories?

P.S. This is preventing the `mod_wsgi` from finding the Django included in the virtualenv and thus the app from running successfully.

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot of the env directory.

[image]

Comment: You copied the full virtualenv to the EC2 instance? But are the *full* paths exactly the same; because these might be hardcoded in the activation script of the virtualenv. Check that script in the virtualenv bin directory on EC2 to verify the paths are correct there.

Comment: Yes, I copied the full virtualenv. Is there a better way of doing this? Also, what is the name of the script?

Comment: `activate.bash` or something like that.

Comment: Why copy the env? Just run `mkvirtualenv` on remote as well?

Comment: @hjpotter92 are you saying that I should create a new env on host and populate it using `pip install requirements`?

Comment: I did that earlier today (after posting this question) and even after I activate the env, the Python and PIP are still used as those from the system directories. I will edit the question with a screenshot from within the `env/bin` directory

Comment: That raises two questsions: 1/ is `/usr/local/bin/python3` an executable, or also a symlink, and 2/ where does `/usr/local/bin/python3` even comes from? It is not installed by default on any system I know of.

Comment: Also, don't post screenshots: copy-paste the actual output and put it in a code block.